# C post-/pre-increment pointers in loop

Tags: c, pointers

If I have the following in main...

```
int i;
int *p;

i = 0;
p = &i;
printf("%x\n", *p);
for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
    printf("%x ", *p++);
}

puts("\n\n");

p = &i;
for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
    printf("%x ", ++*p);
}
```

... I get quite strange output...

```
0 569d8a48 7fff 1 0 569d8a38 7fff 9227ce4 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 569d8b98 7fff 0 0 569d8be9 


1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f 10 11 12 13 14
```

Note that `i` is simply an integer - I wanted to see what would happen if I looked at other memory locations. But the post-/pre-increment difference took me by surprise.

Does anyone know what could cause such events (i.e. how is it possible that the second line is in perfect incremented order)?

Comment: What is surprising you? the first line or the second...

Comment: @PhotographyBum The second line. I probably should have specified that. How could they possibly be in order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C, postfix operators have higher precedence than prefix operators.  So `*p++` is interpreted as if it was written `*(p++)`.  That is, you're incrementing the pointer.  You're then dereferencing to print the integer that happens to be stored at that location in memory.

But `++*p` in interpreted as `++(*p)`, so you're incrementing the value that the pointer is pointing to (i.e. the integer `i`).  That's also the return value of the ++ operator, so that's what you see printed.

Comment: That makes so much sense. Do you happen to know if it is like that in Java? That is what I am coming from, and I thought they had the same precedence (at least they should - I think [: )

Comment: @Dylan in Java one does not increment pointers, nor does one have an operator to explicitly dereference them... But yes, as with all C-family languages, postfix unary operators have higher precendence than prefix unary operators.

Comment: I guess it does extend C, so it would pretty much have to, but that still seems weird. I never actually committed to memory the precedence of unary (or any except for the common ones like parens/brackets, *, /, +, -, &&, ||, ==, =, ? etc.) operators.

Comment: @Dylan Unary operators always have higher precedence and addition/subtraction/multiplication/division/modulo follow normal mathematical conventions, as does logical and bitwise AND/OR. For all other things I explicitly specify in parentheses what happens. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_precedence_in_C#Operator_precedence

Comment: @Iwillnotexist Idonotexist That's what I've heard a bunch of times. I guess I better start making a habit out of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The precedence of `++` and unary `*` operator are the same. The associativity is right to left.

So in the first example `*p++` is equivalent to `*(p++)` (which is undefined behavior). While in the second example `++*p` is equivalent to `++(*p)`.

Comment: Postfix ops have higher precedence, though... You did not mention it, although I infer that you implicitly say that.

Comment: @Dylan operators bind from the inside out; So in the case of `++*p` there is no choice, `*` is applied first, then `++` is applied to `(*p)`. Postfix ops having higher precedence is only useful in deriving what the other case, `*p++`, does.

Comment: So, even if postcrement (++) and pointer (*) were of the same precedence, then the results would be the same?

Comment: @Dylan I'm looking at K&R right now, its precedence table says they are the same. But like you said, I don't think it makes a difference in practice.

Comment: @Dylan Strictly speaking in `++*p` the `++` is _pre_-increment. But indeed, an operator can't "jump the queue" and be applied first if there's another operator between it and the target. Also, the unary post-increment `++` and the unary dereference `*` operators MAY NOT have the same precedence, because then it would be impossible to tell which applied first in the case `*p++`.